# Read EPUB using Java only

Tags: java, android, file-io, epub

I need to read from an EPUB file using a Java only solution.

Could anyone point me towards a tutorial for this, or give me the solution? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [ePub library for java or android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645795/epub-library-for-java-or-android)

Comment: @Mark yes epubLib works with android. I am using it right now developing an app. If you have any questions on how to do something don't hesitate to ask me.

Answer (score 2):

Open Source Epub Reader API for Java Mobile Application See [this](https://sourceforge.net/p/epubreader-omt/) 

You can also refer the code because it is open source Epub Reader API developed in Java it helps you to understand how epub reader works