# how can i get the jar files for making a epub reader application?

Tags: android

please help me ? thanks in advance .for reading epub file my code is as follow?

```
package org.example.mymenu;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
//import java.util.List;

//import nl.siegmann.epublib.domain.Book;
//import nl.siegmann.epublib.domain.TOCReference;
//import nl.siegmann.epublib.epub.EpubReader;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
//import android.graphics.Bitmap;
//import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Log the info of 'assets/books/testbook.epub'.
 *
 * @author paul.siegmann
 *
 */
public class Epub extends Activity {
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    try {
      // find InputStream for book
      InputStream epubInputStream = assetManager
          .open("ActioninWaiting.epub");
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
      Log.e("epublib", e.getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found this interesting link: http://www.siegmann.nl/epublib/android

In this interesting answer: [ePub library for java or android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645795/epub-library-for-java-or-android/3671056#3671056)

I hope that's what you're looking for.