# what can I do for Epub reading through coding in android

Tags: android, epub

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ePub library for java or android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3645795/epub-library-for-java-or-android)

I want to read epub file which i kept in my SD card,I want to read it line by line.
How can I do this please help me

Thank you

Comment: Try using the epublib library: http://www.siegmann.nl/epublib/android

Comment: I also used this but it is not working..some errors r there

Comment: yaa i have tried this but not working can any other way is there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. just extract the epub file and get it contains as a .htm or any .html file and display it in webview just simple. :-)

EDIT: or just [android epub library](http://www.siegmann.nl/epublib/android) of Paul Siegmann

Comment: yaa,ok,but how can I change it to the HTML,there are images also.

Comment: yes< if you refer this in local location that it also take the images.

Comment: so how can I change it to the epub to html

Comment: can you extract epub file? I think it is same as zip or rar file.

Comment: no its not same like zip and rar,its like PDF file,Its Electronic Publication and extention is.epub.like .pdf

Comment: are you developing on windows or linux?

Comment: use ZipFile zipfile = new ZipFile("Epub file"); of 
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipFile;

to extract the epub file.

Comment: but its not zip file then how can??

Comment: where I have to write this code??

Comment: on your activity's onCreate() unzip the epub file extract it on sdcard get the page and display in wenview.

Comment: ok i will try and let u know ,thanks for giving me your time

Comment: wc. if any problem let me inform.

Comment: no I am unable to do it.please send me some code for it..it is not working I am not getting the proper way